# Split Animation Like  Emoji CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i want to make a animation for a circle that splits open on two sides:
kind of like the  emoji flipped upside down. I have two half circle elments and i put them next to each other. I tryed to animate one of the sides but its not really what im going for, i wanted the split to pivot on the bottom of the semi-circle not in the middle. Since the circle is split and right next to each other in two when you rotate one of the halfs it overlaps, i didnt attempt to fix it yet (i was think move it to the left/right over the animation but i dont know...).

```css
  .circlecontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .halfright {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border-top-right-radius: 150px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
    background: orange;
  }

  .halfleft {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border-top-left-radius: 150px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
    background: orange;
    animation: splitleft 3s;
  }
  
  @keyframes splitleft {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(-0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-90deg)
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="circlecontainer">
        <div class="halfleft"></div>
    <div class="halfright"></div>
  </div>
```

thats it! I hope this makes sense since its hard to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforms will always rotate, scale, etc. from the center of the div (by default). In this case you want to pivot from where the circles meet at the bottom, use [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to do this:

```css
  .circlecontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .halfright {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border-top-right-radius: 150px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
    background: orange;
    transform-origin: bottom left; /* THIS ONE!! */
    animation: splitright 3s forwards;
  }

  .halfleft {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border-top-left-radius: 150px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
    background: orange;
    transform-origin: bottom right; /* THIS ONE!! */
    animation: splitleft 3s forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes splitleft {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
  }
  
    @keyframes splitright {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="halfleft"></div>
    <div class="halfright"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: WOW thats perfect thank you so much!!! Will be using this. Also yeah i didnt know about transform-origin

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

```css
.circlecontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.halfright {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border-top-right-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
  background: orange;
  animation: splitright 3s;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.halfleft {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border-top-left-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
  background: orange;
  animation: splitleft 3s;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

@keyframes splitleft {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-0deg)
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
  }
}

@keyframes splitright {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circlecontainer">
  <div class="halfleft"></div>
  <div class="halfright"></div>
</div>
```